# Emacs tab auto-complete for R data.table?

Tags: r, emacs, data.table

Anyone know how to get auto-complete working in Emacs for R data.tables (ess-mode)?

For example when I type tab below I'd like autocomplete to add "alpha"

```
DT <- data.table(alpha = 1:5)
DT[<type tab here>
```

thanks, jason

Comment: I've had the same request for Sublime Text.  I would love to know if there is a way to make this happen

Comment: This seems hard to do because it's context sensitive. And to recognise the context (DT) you have parse code that isn't complete yet. Not impossible, but hard.

Comment: Tab completion works for column names specified using the `$` syntax: `DT$<tab>` will work. I don't think completion is available in ESS for `DT[<tab>, ]`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind typing one more charactor, you can use 'Meta - /' after 'DT[a'